# How to do a bash sort by numerical value contained between two different delimiters in the set of strings

Tags: bash

I have a directory of file names like:

```
DataFile_1.txt
DataFile_2.txt
...
DataFile_9.txt
DataFile_10.txt
DataFile_11.txt
...
DataFile_99.txt
DataFile_100.txt
DataFile_101.txt
...
```

They are NOT in the above order, but I wish them to be.  An ls produces them in a random order, e.g.

```
DataFile_100.txt
DataFile_2.txt
DataFile_19.txt
DataFile_9.txt
...
```

I need the output of a script to be the files in order by the numerical value between the '_' and the '.' character.  I haven't been able to find a way to use the sort command where I sort on the numerical values in a human sense between those delimiters.

`ls | sort -k 10 --human-numeric-sort` still puts the `-8.` after the `_79.` and before the `_80.`

Comment: [List files sorted numerically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [`sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html);

```sh
ls | sort -g -t '_' -k 2
```

- `-g`: Sort on general-numeric
- `-t`: field-separator (`_`)
- `-k`: Key, `2` means: Get second col (after `-t`)

Example:

```sh
-> ls -t
DataFile_42.txt  DataFile_162.txt  DataFile_15.txt  DataFile_1.txt
->
-> ls | sort -g -t '_' -k 2
DataFile_1.txt
DataFile_15.txt
DataFile_42.txt
DataFile_162.txt
```

---

If you add the `--debug` option, we can visually see how `-t` and `-k` works:

```sh
-> ls | sort -g -t '_' -k 2 --debug
sort: text ordering performed using simple byte comparison
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
DataFile_1.txt
         __
______________
DataFile_15.txt
         ___
_______________
DataFile_42.txt
         ___
_______________
DataFile_162.txt
         ____
________________
->
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is surprisingly easy -- just force numerical sort on second column.

```
$ cat files.txt 
DataFile_100.txt
DataFile_2.txt
DataFile_9.txt
DataFile_10.txt
DataFile_1.txt
DataFile_101.txt
DataFile_11.txt
DataFile_99.txt

$ cat files.txt | sort -t'_' -k2,2n
DataFile_1.txt
DataFile_2.txt
DataFile_9.txt
DataFile_10.txt
DataFile_11.txt
DataFile_99.txt
DataFile_100.txt
DataFile_101.txt
```